# Downloads slow on specific computer

Tags: networking, windows-10, performance, internet, connection

***From my /r/TechSupport reddit submission:***

**All computers referenced in this post was done on a ethernet connection**

I have been suffering this issue for the past few months without any solution available. When I download anything (especially from a few specific servers) the download speed never goes above 1-2 megabits (~200 kilobytes per second) a second. However youtube is able to play the video back at around 30-60 megabits per second, whilst speed tests from various websites both report back 90 megabits down and 35 megabits up which is the maximum speed capable of my semi-fibre connection.

I am fully aware that download speeds are dependent on the server that is being used to download a file from (eg server load) and how well the ISP peers with other networks but here is some more info. I downloaded a file from the same server on a different computer and is able to reach around 10-12 megabits per second which I expect as there is around ~300 millisecond latency between me and the server as its in a different country. However on the PC with the issue, downloading the same file off the same server will only reach speeds at around 1-2 megabits per second. To isolate if the issue is with the operating system, I decided to reboot into a live ubuntu usb stick on the problematic PC and downloaded the same file from the same server there and it is able to easily reach around 10-12 megabits per second, which is the same with the other PC I have tested it with.

Some other tests I have done included an iperf3 test, a network bandwidth test tool. I have set up the iperf3 server on a VPS and the client on both the problematic PC and the other computer. Here are the results:

**Problematic PC (Windows 10 - x64):**

```
iperf3.exe -R -c xxx
Connecting to host xxx, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host xxx is sending
[  4] local 10.0.0.2 port 50862 connected to xxx port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   162 KBytes  1.32 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.54 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  3.75 MBytes  3.15 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.93 MBytes  1.62 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

**Other Computer (Macbook Pro - OSX Sierra):**

```
/Users/xxx/Desktop/iperf3 -R -c xxx
Connecting to host xxx, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host xxx is sending
[ 5] local 10.0.0.27 port 58353 connected to xxx port 5201
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth
[ 5] 0.00-1.00 sec 129 KBytes 1.06 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 1.00-2.00 sec 611 KBytes 5.01 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 2.00-3.00 sec 769 KBytes 6.30 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 3.00-4.00 sec 777 KBytes 6.37 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 4.00-5.00 sec 777 KBytes 6.37 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 5.00-6.00 sec 777 KBytes 6.37 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 6.00-7.00 sec 747 KBytes 6.12 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 7.00-8.00 sec 744 KBytes 6.10 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 8.00-9.00 sec 747 KBytes 6.12 Mbits/sec
[ 5] 9.00-10.00 sec 759 KBytes 6.21 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval Transfer Bandwidth Retr
[ 5] 0.00-10.00 sec 12.1 MBytes 10.2 Mbits/sec 0 sender
[ 5] 0.00-10.00 sec 6.93 MBytes 5.81 Mbits/sec receiver

iperf Done.
```

On the problematic pc, the download seems to be capped at 187 kilobytes per second compared to the other computer where it is sitting at around ~770 kilobytes per second.

Another test I have done was to setup a ftp server on both machines and sent a file to both of them from the VPS and the problematic PC stayed at around 190 kilobytes per second and the other computer was at around 700-800 kilobytes per second.

From all my findings it seems to be an issue with the operating system. Not the computer its self. Currently I still do not have a fix for this issue. It would be greatly appreciated if some one could provide some input into this issue.

Specs can be found here:

**Problematic PC:**
[DXDIAG](http://pastebin.com/Ay0TDJSX)

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- CPU: Intel Core i7
- RAM: 16GB
- STORAGE: 120GB SSD, 1TB HDD
- GPU: GTX 970

**Macbook Pro**

- OS: OSX Sierra
- CPU: Intel Core i7
- RAM: 16GB
- STORAGE: 1TB PCI-E Based Flash Storage
- GPU: AMD RADEON R9 M370X, Intel Iris Pro 1536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a fix. After running

```
netsh interface tcp reset
```

Speeds returned back to normal.